# patch to stdout with process substitution

Tags: diff, patch, process-substitution

I am trying to do something like:

```
patch <( zcat data.201301.gz ) patch_file.diff -o /dev/stdout
```

result I am getting is:

```
File /dev/fd/63 is not a regular file -- refusing to patch
4504 out of 4504 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file /dev/stdout.rej
```

How can I produce the patched file with process substitution ?

Comment: Why not zcat to tempfile, and then use tempfile instead of piping? Unless patch can read stdin, nothing else will work. Except building a patch-wrapper, but that is probably out of scope.

Comment: This is what i come up at the end. But disk space is (was) very low and I wanted to do it without unzipping the files.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of patch, this not seems to be possible.

File to be patched must be standard file, any other type of files are rejected.

Unfortunately symlinks, pipes, descriptors etc not working.

Answer (score 0):

To process possible symlinks inside scripts, this helps:

```
patch -o "$out" "$(readlink "$in")" "$diff"
```